# Return text that is different from combo box text

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, excel-2013

I am setting up a combo box to update a pivot table.

I need the value the combo box returns to be different from the selected text.

For example. You select a product's name in the drop down box, "Cheerios". It has a SKU number of 1234. I need the combo box to return the 1234.

Edit:

Below is an image of where I am getting my list populated from. Column B is what is being displayed in the drop down, column A is what I need returned.

[image]

Edit 2:

```
Private Sub cmb_SkuSelect_Click()
    Dim xlSheetSort As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim skuValue As Integer

    Set xlSheetSort = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sort")
    lastRow = xlSheetSort.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

    With xlSheetSort.Range("B1:B" & lastRow)
        Set c = .Find(cmb_SkuSelect.Value, LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not c Is Nothing Then
            skuValue = xlSheetSort.Range("A" & c.Row).Value
        End If
    End With

    cmb_SkuSelect.Value = ""
    ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A4").Value = skuValue

    updatePivot skuValue
End Sub
```

updatePivot:

```
Public Sub updatePivot(ByVal sku As Integer)
    Dim xlSheet As Worksheet
    Dim xlPTable As PivotTable

    Set xlSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sku Inventory")

    For Each xlPTable In xlSheet.PivotTables
        With xlPTable
            .PivotFields("Sku Number").CurrentPage = sku
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What exactly do you mean by return 1234?

Comment: `If ComboBox.Value = "Cheerios" Then` myvalue = "1234" etc. etc

Comment: I haven't tried anything so far because I don't know how to go about it. An If statement won't work for this because I have over 15,000 distinct items in the drop down.

Comment: the their any relation with the drop down item and the SKU number?

Comment: No, drop down list is sorted alphabetically and the SKU #'s do not follow the 1,2,3 when sorting the description.

Answer (score 1):

Try that:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    Dim valueToLook As String
    valueToLook = ComboBox1.Value
    Dim sku, i As Integer
    Dim LastRow As Long
    With ActiveSheet
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    End With
    For i = 1 To LastRow
        If Cells(i, 2).Value = valueToLook Then
            sku = Cells(i, 1).Value
            MsgBox sku
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: An If statement won't work for this because I have over 15,000 distinct items in the drop down.

Comment: why would it not work, you are only selecting one item from the drop down and when that item is selected, it checks if that value is "Cherrios".

Comment: Although, I could add the SKU #'s next to the list for the combo box, and then do some sort of search offset by 1 column to get the SKU value? hmm..

Comment: How do you determine the SKU to the item in the checkbox? Any images or example to show?

Comment: I have a data set where I am pulling the descriptions from. They all have a corresponding SKU in a separate column.

Comment: Please add an example or image to your post.

Comment: Try edited answer. When you select a item from your combobox, it will get the value in column A.

Comment: I tried something like you suggested and it works. The issue I am having now is that when the value is selected and the pivot table is refreshed to apply the filter, it will fire the combobox "_Click" and "_Change" events.

Comment: why would your combobox click be firing? Do you have a event set for click as well?

Comment: I used the _Click event on the combo box instead of _change. I have no idea why it fires when the pivot table updates.

Comment: why are you using the click and not the change?

Comment: It does the same thing as the Click event in my case. Changing it to a "_Change" event does not remedy my problem of it firing after the pivot table refreshes. I'll include my code in my OP.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's definitely possible - all you need to do is make the combobox a multi-column one, set its `BoundColumn` to the SKU Number's column and hide that column afterwards. It's a late answer, but it solves your problem.

I'm not going to bother with your existing structure, but rather present a simple example that you can adapt to your needs afterwards. Assuming you already have the form (e.g. `UserForm1`) and the combobox (e.g. `ComboBox1`) in a standard workbook, paste this into your userform module:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    ' Show the expected result to the user
    MsgBox Me.ComboBox1.Value
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
  Dim cbitems(2, 1) As Variant
    ' Set the number of columns in the combobox to 2 (i.e. Product Name and SKU Number)
    Me.ComboBox1.ColumnCount = 2
    ' Set the 2-nd column's value to be used as the value of the combobox (i.e. the SKU Number)
    Me.ComboBox1.BoundColumn = 2
    ' Set the 2-nd column's width to 0, hiding the column (i.e. only the Product Name is visible)
    Me.ComboBox1.ColumnWidths = ";0"
    ' Populate a 2D array with the values of the combobox columns
    cbitems(0, 0) = "Cheerios"
    cbitems(0, 1) = "1234"
    cbitems(1, 0) = "Apples"
    cbitems(1, 1) = "1672"
    cbitems(2, 0) = "Peaches"
    cbitems(2, 1) = "3722"
    ' Populate the combobox with the above array, using the List method (i.e. not the AddItem one)
    Me.ComboBox1.List = cbitems
    ' Set the 1-st item of the combobox to be its default one
    Me.ComboBox1.ListIndex = 0
End Sub
```

The comments explain what happens. All you have to do is adapt the code to your usage scenario (e.g. you'll probably want to populate the array/combobox using a loop, maybe move the relevant code to a different Sub than the userform's `Initialize` event, potentially add column headers if you want both columns to be visible, etc.)

Note: The `Change` event of the combobox will fire a couple of times when the combobox is first drawn on the userform, so you might get a few empty message-boxes at the start. Don't mind them, the important ones are those after you select some item from the list later on. The message boxes are just for convenience anyway, and, along with the last line in the userform's `Initialize` event, they can be safely removed from the code once you get the idea.

Comment: By the way, don't forget to mark the answer as the accepted one, if it solved your problem.